# Im getting this "SyntaxError: Unexpected token >" Error

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm positive this is an easy fix. I just started learning JavaScript, but have a medium to strong background in Java. I'm currently using CodeAcademy as an instructional guide to learning Javascript. Honestly that may be the actual problem, as veering from the course material and structure (A simple example would be a small syntactical error such as ("Your" instead of "You're")). I may have the code written correctly, but if there is another way I may be able to achieve the desired result, I'm open to all suggestions.

The goal is to create a rock, paper, scissors game. I am to use an if, else, if/else statement to achieve the desired result from the computer.

Structure:

```
if between 0 & 0.33 = rock
if between 0.34 & 0.66 = paper
if between 0.67 & 1 = scissor
```

This is the code I have written so far:

```
var userChoice = prompt ("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random();

console.log(computerChoice);

if(computerChoice >= 0.33){
    console.log("rock");
}
else if(computerChoice => 0.34 && > 0.66 ){
    console.log("paper");
}enter code here
else {
    console.log("scissors");
}
```

Comment: Lesson one - if you are seeing the error, it should also be telling you which line the problem is on. Find the line, find the problem. In this case, it'd be `computerChoice =>` - found it by just looking for all the `>` signs and seeing where the code looks wrong.

Comment: `&& >` is invalid. Binary operators (like `>` and `&&`) must have a valid expression on each side and a binary operator is, by itself, not a valid expression.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your first comparison is wrong. `computerChoice >= 0.33` will match any number greater than 0.33. Use `<=`
2. `=>` is not a valid comparison operator, actually it is not operator in javascript at all.
3. `computerChoice >= 0.33 && > 0.66` makes no sense, comparison opeators needs 2 sides with values. You should've written `computerChoice > 0.33 && computerChoice <= 0.66`
4. As pointed out in comment, no need to compare `computerChoice > 0.33`.

---

```
if(computerChoice <= 0.33){
    console.log("rock");
}
else if(computerChoice <= 0.66 ){
    console.log("paper");
}
else {
    console.log("scissors");
}
```

Comment: Actually you can also drop the `computerChoice > 0.33 &&`, it's already known to be true in the `else`.

Comment: @Bergi yeah, didn't notice. Actually I wrote answer from mobile app